# why doesn't pip freeze > requirements.txt output Django?

Tags: python, django, pip, requirements.txt

I'm trying to deploy my Django site on Heroku, and thus, I need a **requirements.txt** file with the necessary packages that Heroku needs to install for me. I understand Django is a necessary package to be installed. Unfortunately, Django isn't included in the file when I run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Why is this? I'm not sure what to show you so you can tell me what's going wrong. Let me know and I'll add it. FYI the site hosts just fine on my local computer, so Django is definitely installed.

Comment: Are you working on virtualenv.

Comment: Did you install it with pip?

Comment: @advay.umare yes, the whole project is in a virtualenv.

Comment: @sneilan I think so. Is there a way I could check? Or maybe reinstall with pip?

Comment: you have to activate the virtualenv and then do pip freeze from the same terminal / command prompt

Comment: @Stack That is what I'm doing.

Comment: just type `pip freeze`, do you see it in the list?

Comment: After typing `pip install Django==2.0.1`, yes. Maybe that's what was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are working in a virtual environment, yet your Django dependency is installed globally. Check which Python packages are installed globally and uninstall Django (you probably don't need it globally). Then install it into your virtual environment. Now the freeze command should output Django as well.

General note: Most packages should be installed into your project virtual environment. There are only few packages where it makes sense to install them globally (eg aws management tools).